# Remove or replace comma from an index of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to remove or replace comma from index of an array I don't know how to use this

> Array [ "ert,sfdsf", "werwer" ]

I have the array in this format. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

use `replace()` method searches a string for a specified value and replace it.

```js
let array = [ "ert,sfdsf", "werwer" ]

$.each(array, function(i){
  console.log(array[i].replace(',',''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just wonder, since using jQuery's [each method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), its callback function already has pair of index/value, so maybe better [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c3510oem/4/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove commas from all arrays elements, then loop through the array for each element and remove commas.

```
var key = prepareKey(str);//Remove commas.
var index = 0;
for (element : array) {
    array[i] = prepareKey(array[i]);
}
```

If you have a map where keys have commas, then you need to create another map, and copy values there with modified keys.

```
newMap = {};
for (var key in originalMap) {
    if (originalMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        newKey = prepareKey(key);
        newMap[newKey] = originalMap[key];
    }
}
```

And this is `prepareKey`

```
function prepareKey(str) {
    return str.replace(/,/g,"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` on each element of the array:

```js
let arr = ["some, text", "more", "text"]
console.log(arr);

let newArr = arr.map(function(el) { 
  el = el.replace(/,\s+/, ''); 
  return el;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` function:

```js
let array = [ "ert,sfdsf", "werwer" ];
let res = array.map(item => item.replace(/\s*,/g,''));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the "," where is needed.

```
var arr=["aaa,bbbb", "ccccc"]; 
arr[0]=arr[0].replace(",","");
```